# Am I computing conditional expectations correctly?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am building a working model and would like to know whether my computations so far look correct.

I am working with a generally bivariate distribution of two variables $\displaystyle X\sim [ 0,1]$, $\displaystyle Y\sim [ 0,1]$. In general, they might be correlated, but to set ideas I am open to consider extreme cases in which they might be independent. For instance, it could be useful to think about the case in which $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $X\sim U[ 0,1]$, $Y\sim U[ 0,1]$.

I am considering region like this one:

[image]

I want to compute the conditional expectation of $\displaystyle X$ and $\displaystyle Y$ conditional on it being in the regions $\displaystyle A$ and $\displaystyle B$. I am thinking about writing this in the following way:
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[ Y|A] =\mathbb{E}[ Y|Y >r( x)] =\mathbb{E}[ Y|X< r( x)]
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[ Y|B] =1-\mathbb{E}[ Y|A]
\end{equation*}

**Conjecture**
$$
\mathbb{E}[ Y|A] =\begin{cases}
1 & \text{for} \ x< -b/m\\
(1-b-mx)^{-1} & \text{for} \ x\geqslant -b/m
\end{cases}$$

**Question:** does my argument make sense? Are there any other "easy cases" that can allow me to study conditional expectations as the ones above? Below I work with bivariate uniform. I have also been checking [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195433/difference-between-joint-density-and-density-function-of-sum-of-two-independent), which seems like it could be potentially helpful.

**Sketch of my argument:**

consider:

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[ Y|A] =\mathbb{E}[ Y|X< r( x)] =\int {_{0}}^{1} yf_{Y|X< r( x)}( y|x) dy
\end{equation*}

We can compute the expectation by characterizing the marginal distribution:

\begin{equation*}
f_{Y|X< r( x)}( y|x) =\frac{f( x,y)}{f_{X< r( x)}( x)}
\end{equation*}

The marginal above is decribed by :
\begin{equation*}
f_{X< r( x)}( x) =\int _{A} f( x,y) \ dy=\int _{A} f( x,y) \ dy=\begin{cases}
\int _{0}^{1} f( x,y) dy & \text{for} \ x< -b/m\\
\int _{mx+b}^{1} f( x,y) dy & \text{for} \ x\geqslant -b/m
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Assume that $\displaystyle f(x,y) =1$. Then we have that:
\begin{equation*}
f_{X< r( x)}( x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{for} \ x< -b/m\\
1-b-mx & \text{for} \ x\geqslant -b/m
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

And hence the expected value is given by:
\begin{gather*}
\int_{0}^{1} yf_{Y|X< r( x)}(y|x) dy\\
 =\begin{cases}
\int_{0}^{1} y\ dy & \text{for} \ x< -b/m\\
\int_{0}^{1} y( 1-b-mx)^{-1} dy & \text{for} \ x\geqslant -b/m
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{for} \ x< -b/m\\
(1-b-mx)^{-1}& \text{for} \ x\geqslant -b/m
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}

Comment: Is the line always meant to go through (1,1) ? If so $b=1-m$ and the line is $Y-1=m(X-1)$

Comment: Also, $A$ is the event that $Y>r(X)$ ... (not lowercase $x$).  That is $Y>mX+b$ or $X<(Y-b)/m$

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking about writing this in the following way:
> $$\begin{align}
> \mathbb{E}[ Y|A] &=\mathbb{E}[ Y|Y >r( x)]\\& =\mathbb{E}[ Y|X< r( x)]
> \\[2ex]\mathbb{E}[ Y|B] &=1-\mathbb{E}[ Y|A]
> \end{align}$$

**Firstly**, what is that *lowercase* $x$ doing in the first equation?

$A$ is the area above/to the left of the line (and inside the unit square), so it represents the event of $Y>r(X)$ where $r(X)=mX+b$.

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[ Y\mid A] &=\mathbb{E}[ Y\mid Y > mX+b]\\& =\mathbb{E}[ Y\mid X< (Y-b)/m]
\end{align}$$

---

**Secondly**, your second equation does not hold in general.

Rather: $\mathbb E[Y]=\mathbb P(A)\,\mathbb E[Y\mid A]+\mathbb P(B)\,\mathbb E[Y\mid B]$ by the Law of Total Expectation, so we have:

$$\begin{align}\mathbb E[Y\mid B] &= \dfrac{\mathbb E[Y]-\mathbb P(A)\,\mathbb E[Y\mid A]}{\mathbb P(B)}\\[1ex]&= \dfrac{\mathbb E[Y]-\mathbb P(A)\,\mathbb E[Y\mid A]}{1-\mathbb P(A)}\end{align}$$

---

**Thirdly**, you have *two* random variables, so your expectations shall be evaluated using double integrals.

$$\mathbb E[Y\mid A] = \dfrac{\displaystyle\iint_{A} y\, f_{X,Y}(x, y)\,\mathrm d(x,y)}{\displaystyle\iint_{A} f_{X,Y}(x, y)\,\mathrm d(x,y)}$$

---

**Fourthly**, the shapes of $A$ will be either a triangle, quadrilateral, or pentagon, depending on which *two* sides (or corners) of the square the line intercepts.   Determining the bounds of the integrals will need *more information* than that $x$-intercept.